# Ethereum mining on Android?

Tags: mining, ethminer, android

Is it possible to mine Ethereum on an Android device?

I know it may be inefficient, but still I want to see if I can develop and app that mines Ethereum on Android.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically, yes. You could running the mining calculations on an Android device. You will never see a return, it's simply too inefficient.

Moreover, Google Play [recently banned](https://www.androidheadlines.com/2018/07/google-play-bans-cryptocurrency-mining-apps-other-content.html) cryptocurrency mining apps.

Comment: Awe thanks, I don't want to put my app on Google play.

Comment: And how can I do it? Would you let me know about a library that can mine on Android?

Comment: I don't know of any library that does that, I doubt someone would bother writing well-maintained library for it because it doesn't make any sense too. Your best bet would be to take some existing Java library or go through the mining code in Geth and convert it to Java/kotlin.

Comment: Take a look at [ethereumJ](https://github.com/ethereum/ethereumj/tree/develop/ethereumj-core/src/main/java/org/ethereum/mine), pure Java implementation. Might be portable to android